# MSSQL to POSTGRES conversion

Tags: postgresql

Anyone can help me with the following query from mssql to postgres?

```
DateAdd(Week,-(doc.[DelaiLivraisonNum]),Convert(date,sas.DateFin)) as IdDate
```

where `DelaiLivraisonNum` and `DateFin` are columns

Thanks

Comment: Postgres is much simpler when it comes to date/time arithmetic. Just use something like `DateFin - interval DelaiLivraisonNum weeks`.

Answer (score 0):

I always struggle with the SQL Server syntax, but I *think* this would be the equivalent (it's hard to tell as you did not explain *what* your code does):

```
datefin::date - make_interval(weeks => delailivraisonnum)
```

This assumes that `datefin` can be cast to a `date` (e.g. because it's a `timestamp`)  and `delailivraisonnum` is an integer.

Comment: Hello,we are doing a migration of mssql code to postgres due to client demand and frankly speaking, am not quite familiar with what the code actually does. we only have to convert this working mssql code to postgres keeping its utility.            sas."DateFin"::date - make_interval(weeks => cast (doc."DelaiLivraisonNum" as integer)) am i doing it right? because am having an error that column "weeks" does not exist

Comment: @Hemraj: no offense, but how can you migrate code where you don't know what it does? How are you going to test that?

Comment: i only check if the code is a valid postgres code. there is another team who test for the output generated

Comment: @Hemraj: well, `datefin::date +  delailivraisonnum::int` would also be valid Postgres code, but would to something different.

Comment: i get you but the context would be different. i agree that it is difficult to help in this situation. Thanks for trying to help though

Comment: (sas."DateFin"::date - cast (doc."DelaiLivraisonNum" as integer) * '1 week'::interval) as IdDate ... sharing my solution

Comment: `make_interval()` will do the same.

Comment: i tried it but it is giving error that columns weeks does not exists. it should be a syntax error on the code i built. Thanks anyway @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @Hemraj: then you are using an unsupported Postgres version